# How to make calls to the == operator to call the child's implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, operator-keyword, overriding

I have

```
public abstract class DataClass
{
    public static bool operator ==(DataClass left, DataClass right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }
}
```

and this is what happens

```
object left = new DataClass();
object right = new DataClass();
bool expected = true;
bool actual;
actual = ((DataClass)left) == ((DataClass)right);
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); // passes
actual = left == right;
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); // fails
```

How to make it call the right implementation, without casting it explicitly?

Comment: If the class is mutable and/or not `sealed`, then overriding `operator==` in the first place is most likely wrong. You should always use `Equals` instead of `==` *unless you know that this specific class plays well with equality*. Since `object` is far away from this ideal, do not do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`static` methods are not subject to polymorphic behavior (i.e. they cannot be overriden). The cast is required.

For a possible workaround see this related question: [Override a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074454/override-a-static-method)

Most likely you will have to resort to creating an instance method or overriding `Equals` instead.

Comment: I have overridden Equals, but the operator== doesn't call Equals unless you implement it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as operators are static and by definition they can not be virtual / overriden.

In cases where I've had the same issue I ended up overriding `bool Equals(object o)` and using the method instead of the operator. If that is not an option then the cast is necessary.