# Need to overwrite XMLWriter's method

Tags: c#, overriding

I need to overwrite the XMLWriter's method "WriteElementString" to not write the element if the value is empty, the code bellow didn't work, tried **override** and **new** keywords but it still goes to the framework method.

```
public static void WriteElementString(this XmlWriter writer,
                                      string localName,
                                      string value)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(localName);
        writer.WriteString(value);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

The answer was close but correct solution is:

```
public abstract class MyWriter : XmlWriter
{
    private readonly XmlWriter writer;
    public Boolean skipEmptyValues;

    public MyWriter(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (writer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Writer");
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public new void WriteElementString(string localName, string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && skipEmptyValues)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteElementString(localName, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't actually override static method. Not directly at least. Here is a good question/answer about similar problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074454/override-a-static-method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create an object that decorates `XmlWriter` to achieve what you are trying to do.  [More on the Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

```
public class MyXmlWriter : XmlWriter
{
    private readonly XmlWriter writer;

    public MyXmlWriter(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (writer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    // This will not be a polymorphic call
    public new void WriteElementString(string localName, string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return;

        this.writer.WriteElementString(localName, value);
    }

    // the rest of the XmlWriter methods will need to be implemented using Decorator Pattern
    // i.e.
    public override void Close()
    {
        this.writer.Close();
    }
    ...
}
```

Using the above object in LinqPad

```
var xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true
};

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlBuilder, xmlSettings))
using (var myWriter = new MyXmlWriter(writer))
{
    // must use myWriter here in order for the desired implementation to be called
    // if you pass myWriter to another method must pass it as MyXmlWriter
    //    in order for the desired implementation to be called
    myWriter.WriteStartElement("Root"); 
    myWriter.WriteElementString("Included", "Hey I made it");
    myWriter.WriteElementString("NotIncluded", "");
}

xmlBuilder.ToString().Dump();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <Included>Hey I made it</Included>
</Root>
```

What you are trying to do, is to override a method using an extension method which is not what they are intended to do. See the [Binding Extension Methods at Compile Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) section on the Extension Methods MSDN Page The compiler will always resolve `WriteElementString` to the instance implemented by `XmlWriter`.  You would need to manually call your extension method `XmlWriterExtensions.WriteElementString(writer, localName, value);` in order for your code to execute as you have it.

Comment: I have a problem, the compiler wants me to implement all functions that were available n the original XmlWriter class plus I could not override WriteElementString as it says "cannot override ... because it is not marked virtual, abastract, or override".

Comment: Making the class abstract solves most of the errors but still can't override WriteElementString.

Comment: Ok, I had to use "new" instead of "override".

Comment: @paul-2011 Well that's curious that `WriteElementString` is not `virtual`.  But be aware that using `new` does not make the function call polymorphic.  And as part of the `Decorator Pattern` you should implement simple pass-through calls instead of marking the class as abstract.

Comment: My code didn't work actually, it's throwing "InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter' to type  MyWriter". when I do "StringBuilder XMLBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            XmlWriterSettings XMLSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            XMLSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; MyWriter  Writer = (MyWriter)MyWriter.Create(XMLBuilder, XMLSettings);"

Comment: @paul-2011 Your not creating `MyWriter` correctly.  When using the `Decorator Pattern` you first instantiate an instance of `XmlWriter` then provide that to the decorator's constructor.

Comment: Why has this been the accepted answer if it still does not provide working code?

Comment: @WolfgangRoth The above code is not a complete example, it does have some gaps.  A straight copy and paste won't compile.  If you are having issues, you should post a question and the community will be happy to help.