# Sharing static fields among different generic class instances

Tags: c#, generics, static

I know that a generic type will not be shared among instances of different close constructed types. This means that for a generic class `C<T>` which has a static field `X`, the values of `C<int>.X` and `C<string>.X` have completely different, independent values.
In my case I really need to have a static field shared between instances with different generic arguments.
The only solution i found was "*define a non-generic base class to store your static members, then set your generic type to inherit from this type.*"
The problem is that my class is already inherit from other .net class.
Is there other way to solve this?

Comment: What is the purpose for the static field?. Perhaps with some understanding of the purpose, suggestions could be made for alternative solutions.

Comment: Have you considered just creating a separate class to store the static field?  It doesn't have to have any inheritance relationship to your generic type.

Comment: If your class is generic; it probably shouldn't be sharing `static` state. Also, using `static` for this is a *huge* code smell, and it should probably be done differently.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, that's a gross generalization.  It's not too uncommon that when I have a generic type, I cache some useful information -- with respect to a particular type argument -- in a static field.

Comment: Have you looked at [Override a static method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2074454/15880)? (I realize this is for static methods rather than static variables, but you could still use a method to do it)

Comment: @KirkWoll But you aren't trying to share that state against *every* type argument. I'm not saying there are no use cases; (smells can turn out ok) but you should know what you are doing, which the OP may (probably does?) not

Comment: my static field is private, and it need to be static and only one for all instances. it will be used for class inheritance from my main class

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I'm often trying to share state for each permutation of type arguments.  For example, it can be a great technique for storing reflection objects (`MethodInfo`, etc.) and expression trees that you've generated for a particular set of type arguments.  It has the added bonus of allowing for lazy-initialization in a thread-safe way (since execution of static initilizers is guaranteed to be thread-safe).

Comment: @AlexanderLeyvaCaro Is the other .NET class from which your generic type already inherits itself generic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could farm the requests off to an internal non-generic class to store the shared data:

```
public class Bar{}
public class FooGeneric<T> : Bar
{
    public static string SharedData {
        get {
            return Foo.SharedData;
        }
        set{
            Foo.SharedData = value;
        }
    }
}

internal class Foo
{
    public static string SharedData = "Fizz";
}
```

usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(FooGeneric<string>.SharedData);    // "Fizz"

FooGeneric<string>.SharedData = "Buzz";
Console.WriteLine(FooGeneric<string>.SharedData);    // "Buzz"

Console.WriteLine(FooGeneric<int>.SharedData);       // "Buzz"
```

Comment: why need to be internal?

Comment: It doesn't need to be,  but it hides the implementation details. There's no reason why you couldn't have clients just use the non-generic class directly.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from a non-generic base class that inherits from the other .NET class from which your generic class currently inherits. Store your shared static state there. Of course, this will not work if the other .NET class is itself generic; luckily, you indicated that is not the case.

Comment: that solve my problem, thanks. but there will be no other cleaner solution?