# How to create a static variable shared amongst instances of closed constructed generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, static, polymorphism

I want to be able to have this generic class:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
  static public string SharedString;
}
```

Where `SharedString` will be a static value that have the same value for all instances of closed constructed types.

Hence theses instances:

```
var instanceInt = new MyClass<int>();
var instanceString = new MyClass<string>();
```

Will have the same value for the field `SharedString`.

For example, if I write:

```
instanceInt.SharedString = "Text 1";
instanceString.SharedString = "Text 2";
```

Then I want that `instanceInt.SharedString == "Text 2"`.

In C#, `SharedString` have the same value for all instances of `MyClass<int>` but it is different from `SharedString` of instances of `MyClass<string>`.

So `instanceInt.SharedString == "Text 1"`.

I want to be able to reuse this concept to create any class with any true *generic static* field that can be `public` as well as `private` or `internal`.

I read that but it is inadequate as I don't want to repeat code each time I need a shared value:
[Sharing static fields among different generic class instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067160/sharing-static-fields-among-different-generic-class-instances)

I don't want to create a base class for each generic type nor nested or wrapper classes: it is too laborious, heavy and not factorized. I just want to be able to define several generic open types and put in them some shared static vars.

How to solve this generic polymorphism flaw?

Comment: You can have a non-generic base class define the static variable.

Comment: ^-- see https://dotnetfiddle.net/rvzln9

Comment: With `new MyClass`, the `SharedString` will be instantiated a new one also.
You could use `Singleton` or `Observer` `design pattern`. With Singleton you will have one and only one instance of MyClass so you will get the same ShardString value every time. With Observer pattern, if you change your ShardString, you can notify every MyClass instances about the change and you can have the same SharedString value in every instance of your MyClass.

Comment: @peeyushsingh Interresting, I did not think about that, but I do not want to create a base class for each of my generic types, it's too laborious and heavy.

Comment: @koviroli Too laborious and heavy. I don't want to create a global var, I want the field encapsulated and the concept reusable. I just want to be able to add on the fly a true *generic static* field in my generic classes on day-to-day work.

Comment: Closed generic types are different type, i.e MyClass<String> , MyClass<int> so they cannot share static instance. Not as per the standards, whichever way you choose, it will be a workaround. Have a look at this, looks interesting as you will not need to inherit from a base class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067160/sharing-static-fields-among-different-generic-class-instances

Comment: You will have to use some form of shared variable, so either a non-generic base class with the static field in it, or a different static type altogether. As far as I know, there's no built-in type that allows you to declare a shared instance for this kind of thing, so you have to declare it yourself. You could create your own type that allows you to specify the shared instance by key, sort of like a static dictionary, you would then have to declare this once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's 3 ways that I can think of that would work for you:

1. Create a non-generic base class holding the shared field(s)
2. Create a non-generic separate class holding the shared field(s)
3. Create a non-generic type that *holds* these shared values, and reuse this inside your generic ones

For the third one, since you say you don't really want option 1 or 2, here's an example:

```
public abstract class Shared
{
    private readonly static Dictionary<Guid, object> _Variables
        = new Dictionary<Guid, object>();

    protected void SetValue<T>(Guid key, T value)
    {
        lock (_Variables)
            _Variables[key] = value;
    }

    protected T GetValue<T>(Guid key)
    {
        object temp;
        lock (_Variables)
            if (!_Variables.TryGetValue(key, out temp))
                return default;

        return (T)temp;
    }
}

public class Shared<T> : Shared
{
    private readonly Guid _Key;

    public Shared(Guid key)
    {
        _Key = key;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get => GetValue<T>(_Key);
        set => SetValue<T>(_Key, value);
    }
}
```

You would use this like this:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private static readonly Shared<string> _Shared
        = new Shared<string>(Guid.Parse("521ecaba-2a5e-43f2-90e0-fda38a32618c"));

    public void Set(string value)
    {
        _Shared.Value = value;
    }

    public void Get()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_Shared.Value);
    }
}
```

The Set/Get methods of that MyClass was used to test that a value set through one closed type is available through another, like this:

```
var mc1 = new MyClass<int>();
var mc2 = new MyClass<string>();

mc1.Set("Test");
mc2.Get();
```

This will output `Test`.

Even though all closed types of `MyClass<T>` will have their own static `Shared<T>` instance, the *value* contained in that instance will be backed by a shared dictionary that is shared between all types using this `Shared<T>` type.

---

Personally I would recommend going with the static non-generic base class though:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    protected static string _Shared;
}

public class MyClass<T> : MyClass
{
    public void Set(string value)
    {
        _Shared = value;
    }

    public void Get()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_Shared);
    }
}
```

If you prefer the "base class", that is, the type holding the shared value, to be unavailable, and not much with base classes (which wouldn't work with structs either), you can easily just make it a completely separate class:

```
internal static class MyClassShared
{
    public static string Shared;
}

public class MyClass<T>
{
    public void Set(string value)
    {
        MyClassShared.Shared = value;
    }

    public void Get()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyClassShared.Shared);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. I improved the solution with the guid and the dictionary to be generic and reusable as-is in one line.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is my solution derived from that of @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Using the Guid and the Dictionary idea.

It finally works and it is as great as simple!

I estimate that the advantage of the factorization and the reusability of his solution outweighs other repetitive code and performance-reducing.

Code can now be reduced and be more maintainable.

Thanks.

#### The SharedStaticValue class

```
public class SharedStaticValue<T>
{

  static private class Collector
  {
    static private readonly object locker = new object();
    static private readonly Dictionary<Guid, object> _Values
        = new Dictionary<Guid, object>();
    static internal void SetValue<T>(Guid key, T value)
    {
      lock ( locker )
        if ( _Values.ContainsKey(key) )
          _Values[key] = value;
        else
          _Values.Add(key, value);
    }
    static internal T GetValue<T>(Guid key)
    {
      lock ( locker )
        if ( _Values.ContainsKey(key) )
          return (T)_Values[key];
        else
        {
          T value = default(T);
          _Values.Add(key, value);
          return value;
        }
    }
  }

  private readonly Guid ID;

  public T Value
  {
    get { return Collector.GetValue<T>(ID); }
    set { Collector.SetValue(ID, value); }
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Value.ToString();
  }

  public SharedStaticValue(Guid id)
  {
    ID = id;
  }

}
```

#### The test

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
  static public int Value
  {
    get { return _Value.Value; }
    set { _Value.Value = value; }
  }
  static private SharedStaticValue<int> _Value
    = new SharedStaticValue<int>(Guid.Parse("521ecaba-2a5e-43f2-90e0-fda38a32618c"));
}

internal class Class1 : GenericClass<int>
{
}

internal class Class2 : GenericClass<string>
{
}

internal class SharedStaticValueTest
{
  private SharedStaticValue<int> value 
    = new SharedStaticValue<int>(Guid.Parse("{E838689A-3B2C-4BFB-A15C-2F1B5D65F1DE}"));
  public void RunTest()
  {
    Action<string> write = (str) =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine(str);
      Console.WriteLine("  this.SharedStaticValue<int> = " + value.Value);
      Console.WriteLine("  GenericClass<double> = " + GenericClass<double>.Value);
      Console.WriteLine("  GenericClass<int> = " + GenericClass<int>.Value);
      Console.WriteLine("  Class1 extend GenericClass<int> = " + Class1.Value);
      Console.WriteLine("  Class2 extend GenericClass<string> = " + Class2.Value);
      Console.WriteLine();
    };
    write("Default values");
    value.Value = 10;
    write("Set this.SharedStaticValue<int>.Value = 10");
    GenericClass<double>.Value = 20;
    write("Set GenericClass<double>.Value = 20");
    GenericClass<int>.Value = 30;
    write("Set GenericClass<int>.Value = 30");
    Class1.Value = 40;
    write("Set Class1 extend GenericClass<int>.Value = 40");
    Class2.Value = 50;
    write("Set Class2 extend GenericClass<string>.Value = 50");
  }
}
```

#### The output

```
Default values
  this.SharedStaticValue<int> = 0
  GenericClass<double> = 0
  GenericClass<int> = 0
  Class1 extend GenericClass<int> = 0
  Class2 extend GenericClass<string> = 0

Set this.SharedStaticValue<int>.Value = 10
  this.SharedStaticValue<int> = 10
  GenericClass<double> = 0
  GenericClass<int> = 0
  Class1 extend GenericClass<int> = 0
  Class2 extend GenericClass<string> = 0

Set GenericClass<double>.Value = 20
  this.SharedStaticValue<int> = 10
  GenericClass<double> = 20
  GenericClass<int> = 20
  Class1 extend GenericClass<int> = 20
  Class2 extend GenericClass<string> = 20

Set GenericClass<int>.Value = 30
  this.SharedStaticValue<int> = 10
  GenericClass<double> = 30
  GenericClass<int> = 30
  Class1 extend GenericClass<int> = 30
  Class2 extend GenericClass<string> = 30

Set Class1 extend GenericClass<int>.Value = 40
  this.SharedStaticValue<int> = 10
  GenericClass<double> = 40
  GenericClass<int> = 40
  Class1 extend GenericClass<int> = 40
  Class2 extend GenericClass<string> = 40

Set Class2 extend GenericClass<string>.Value = 50
  this.SharedStaticValue<int> = 10
  GenericClass<double> = 50
  GenericClass<int> = 50
  Class1 extend GenericClass<int> = 50
  Class2 extend GenericClass<string> = 50
```

Comment: I would avoid setting the value to default in the constructor. If you declare the **use** of your `SharedStaticValue<T>` object as static, it will only be initialized when you first use that class. If you have already given a shared variable a value, it will be reset back to default when you construct the new instance of the new type. Example, you use `MyClass<string>`, and your shared value is constructed, intializing its value to default. Then you give it a value. Then you start using `MyClass<int>`, which gets its own shared value, again initializing it back to default.'

Comment: Basically, I would remove the constructor with the initial value, as you don't know if it is "initial" any more, and I would remove the lines from the constructor(s) that sets the value to default, as you don't know if you have already given the shared object a value.

Comment: Hope my comments make sense, otherwise let me know and I'll whip up an example of what I mean.

Comment: You're right, I removed the constructor with a value. Thanks.

Comment: Also, and this is just a minor optimization, to check if the key is present AND get the value, I would consider using `.TryGetValue` instead of `Contains` + `[key]`.

Comment: Yes, it would be just a minor change to your getter method, you would still have the same construct as you currently have. But it's minor, not really necessary.

Comment: Calling [TryGetValue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/System/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,2e5bc6d8c0f21e67,references) do more things than [ContainsKey](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/System/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,22fd7cd7408aed6e,references) as it creates a `default(T)` eachtime. But indeed, it is a very minor performance issue.

Comment: It only hashes once though, both Contains and accessing the indexer will do the hash. Anyway, minor, looks solid what you got.